# How to sync position only one time, using Photon Networking

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I want to do the following.
When a player joins the room, he should receive all the gameobjects' (with a photonview) locations.
This should happen only once when the player enters the room. 
How could this be implemented?

Comment: I used OnPhotonSerializeView to send the position of all gamepbjects at a certain sendrate. But this is quite inefficient because i would like to only send the positions once when someone joins the room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for sending only one piece of information is to use RPC messages system.

```
[PunRPC]
void changePos(int x, int y, int z)
{
    Debug.Log("new pos =" + x + "," + y + ","+z);
}

PhotonView photonView = PhotonView.Get(this);
photonView.RPC("changePos", PhotonTargets.All, 1,1,1 );
```

You can read more about RPC messages here: https://doc.photonengine.com/en/pun/current/tutorials/rpcsandraiseevent

EDIT:

I'm guessing you're connecting through:

```
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(this.roomName);
```

So in the place resposible for connection to the server you can use:

```
public void OnCreatedRoom()
{
    Debug.Log("OnCreatedRoom");
}

public void OnJoinedRoom()
{
    Debug.Log("OnJoinedRoom");
    RPCserver.Instance.AddNewPlayer(login)      
}
```

And then, you can have a bridge to store all RPC enabled methods:

```
public class RPCserver : Singleton
{
    public List<Player> players = new List<Player>();

    public void addNewPlayer(string name)
    {
            Player p = new Player(name);
            players.Add(p);

            if( p.isNewPlayer() ) fetchOtherObjectsPositions();
    }

    private void fetchOtherObjectsPositions(){
        // Go through all neccesery objects, and send their position via RPCserver
    }
}
```

Is that make sense ?

Comment: You didn't explain how I can send the rpc to only the new client that just joined the room, and you didn't explain how the other clients know when and which new player joined the room.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, but for the sake of simplicity I think I should use `OnPhotonPlayerConnected`. Its the same thing just shorter and without creating a Singleton class.